# Automatically starting svnserve on Snow Leopard

Tags: mac-osx, svn, osx-snow-leopard, svnserve

I have installed Subversion onto my iMac running Snow Leopard, but am having trouble getting svnserve to start up automatically. As I understand it (I'm still fairly green with OSX), the best way to do that is to utilize launchd. To that end, I have created the following .plist file in the /Library/LaunchDaemons folder. If I use launchctl to execute this file, svnserve starts as expected, but it doesn't automatically start when the system starts up or I log in.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>Disabled</key>
<false/>
<key>Label</key>
<string>org.tigris.subversion.svnserve</string>
<key>UserName</key>
<string>Dave</string>
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>/opt/subversion/bin/svnserve</string>
    <string>--inetd</string>
    <string>--root=/Users/Shared/SVNrep</string>
</array>
<key>ServiceDescription</key>
<string>Subversion Standalone Server</string>
<key>Sockets</key>
<dict>
    <key>Listeners</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>SockFamily</key>
            <string>IPv4</string>
            <key>SockServiceName</key>
            <string>svn</string>
            <key>SockType</key>
            <string>stream</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SockFamily</key>
            <string>IPv6</string>
            <key>SockServiceName</key>
            <string>svn</string>
            <key>SockType</key>
            <string>stream</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
<key>inetdCompatibility</key>
<dict>
    <key>Wait</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

If anyone here could provide any suggestions as to how to get this to work, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: There is usually something you have to do to add the "service" to a "runlevel". I'm not sure what the terms are for MacOS.

Comment: @sims like on BSD systems, Mac OS X doesn't have runlevels

Comment: Maybe all BSDs do not have runlevels, but from what I remember, they do have some kind of init sequence and single and multi user "modes". You can enable what services you would like started by editing rc.conf. There are startup scripts in rc.d. Of course, MacOS may not have any of that, which is why this is just a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this key

```
<key>RunAtLoad</key>
<true/>
```

(at the same 'level' than Disabled, Label, ... keys

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work. I then removed it and added the OnDemand key, but that made no difference either. In both cases, I rebooted the machine after each config change.

Comment: Try to change Listeners section with a simplier config like listing 3 on http://developer.apple.com/macosx/launchd.html or try a non inetd setup.

Comment: When I use the simpler Listeners section from section 3, I get 'bind() : Permission denied' when attempting to load the .plist file using launchctl. I'm not sure what you mean by 'try a non inetd setup'. Can you please give an example? All I am trying to achieve is have my SVN repository available to multiple machines on my LAN. If there is a simpler way to achieve this that you know of, feel free to share.

Comment: You use --inetd option, so you must have a Listeners, this makes the configuration more complicated, try without that. Take a look the plist that you can download here: http://www.scottboms.com/2007/03/launchsvnserveatstartup/ this lanunch svnserve as a deamon.

Comment: That plist file has the same symptom. It works if I use launchctl load, but doesn't restart svnserve on reboot (and launchctl list shows no sign of the .plist)

Answer (score 1):

I've not created any `launchd` plists in `inetdCompatibility` mode, but I've found running programs in daemon mode w/`KeepAlive`'s `NetworkState` set to `true` to work pretty well. You have to use `NetworkState` when running in daemon mode as `launchd` doesn't do dependancies at all, so the daemon almost always gets started before the network is up.

So, I'd probably try a `/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.tigris.subversion.svnserve.plist` that looked like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
        <dict>
                <key>Label</key>
                <string>org.tigris.subversion.svnserve</string>
                <key>ProgramArguments</key>
                <array>
                        <string>/opt/subversion/bin/svnserve</string>
                        <string>-d</string>
                        <string>--root=/Users/Shared/SVNrep</string>
                </array>
                <key>RunAtLoad</key>
                <true/>
                <key>KeepAlive</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>NetworkState</key>
            <true/>
                </dict>
        </dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of options that I found.

First, http://www.kashum.com/blog/1217783696 describes using the plist method, but it appears to specify more options in the xml than you're using.

Second, http://www.scottboms.com/2007/03/launchsvnserveatstartup/ describes using an prebuilt working plist file to drop into the LaunchDaemons folder, modify the path specified, and then run

```
sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.tigris.Subversion.plist
```

and verify that it's working with

```
sudo launchctl list
```

(or, y'know, trying to use svn...)